# Is there any reason why you cannot use flash memory for a hard disk?

Tags: memory-hardware

Is there a reason why you cannot use flash memory as a HD? Less moving parts and more affordable. Whats not to like?

Why dont we see Pci-express cards with a couple of terrabytes of flash memory that you can use as a HD?

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with Computer Science. Second, why not an SSD drive? Three, it's terabytes, not terrabytes. Last, who says this is more affordable than a hard drive?

Comment: SSD's **are** built from flash memory. Also, they're block storage devices just like HDD's, so from a Computer Science perspective the two are identical.

Comment: We do that. It's called Solid-State Drive or SSD. You're wrong about more affordable.

Comment: @MSalters SSDs behave differently from HDDs. (You can only erase large blocks, for example, and data that you try to erase for security reasons can remain _somewhere_ if not done carefully.) I don’t know if that is enough CS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first flash disk was introduced in 1987. That's 36 years ago.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#Flash-based_SSDs

So, no, there is no reason.